# Loading two different SQL tables in a single JSP file using spring + hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

Sorry, I edited my post due to a misleading error i posted.

I have two tables on MySQL and I am trying to display both of them in a single JSP page.

I am using `@RequestMapping` to try to achieve this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listFolders(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("folders", new Folders());
    model.addAttribute("listFolders", this.foldersService.listFolders());
    return "person"; //name of the jsp page
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/folders", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listPersons(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
    model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
    return "person"; //name of the jsp page
}
```

I need to show both tables in the same JSP page, but if i try to access /folders i get erros because it wont recognise the person table.

actions in my JSP file:

```
<c:if test="${!empty listPersons}">
<table class="tg">
<tr>
    <th width="80">Person ID</th>
    <th width="120">Person Name</th>
    <th width="120">Person Country</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${listPersons}" var="person">
    <tr>
        <td>${person.id} </td>
        <td>${person.name}</td>
        <td>${person.country}</td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

And:

```
    <c:if test="${!empty listFolders}">
<table class="tg">
<tr>
    <th width="80">Folders ID</th>
    <th width="120">Folders Parent</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${listFolders}" var="person">
    <tr>
        <td>${folders.id} </td>
        <td>${folders.parent}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Erros:

```
Jun 06, 2017 5:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path 
[/CitelumApp] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither 
BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'person' available as 
request attribute] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'person' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>
```

**My question is:** 
Is there a way to display two different SQL tables on the same JSP page?

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to what Boukobba said, you should really look at the error message. You cannot have two mappings with the same url and same request method. The Dispatcher servlet cant figure out on which one to route your request. Things you may consider changing is your    RequestMethod or your    URL

**EDIT**

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listFolders(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, BindingResult personResult, @ModelAttribute("folders") Folders folders, BindingResult folderError, Model model) {
    // you can access folders and person as new Object in JSP
    
    model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
    return "person"; //name of the jsp page
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/folders", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listFolders(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, BindingResult personResult, @ModelAttribute("folders") Folders folders, BindingResult folderError, Model model) {
    // you can access folders and person as new Object in JSP
    
    model.addAttribute("listFolders", this.foldersService.listFolders());
  
    return "person"; //name of the jsp page
}
```

However, there is no point of having two `get` request serving the same page, generally. You may have a request parameter `Boolean` which tells you whether the user wants a folder list or person list. In controller you populate based on that parameter. In JSP access the corresponding folder or persons list checking that same parameter.

Comment: I see what you mean. 
But how can i call 2 different tables with just one GET?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

a route is specified for one action. so you can not use `@RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)` twice with the same value. please change persons to folders for example on listOfFolders.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/folder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: thanks for your response.

I know i can change that. But i allways get an error in the jsp file, because i am calling functions like ${person.name} and ${person.id}.

So, if i put value /folder, it wont recognise the person table

Comment: can you post a part of your jsp ( foreach loop)?

Comment: Share some code and elaborate what you are trying to achieve. You may try putting all the `model.addAttribute()` in one controller mapping and use only that controller mapping